# Loading multiple files with bobobo-etl

Tags: python, bonobo-etl

I'm new to bonobo-etl and I'm trying to write a job that loads multiple files at once but I can't get the CsvReader to work with the `@use_context_processor` annotation. A snippet of my code:

```
def input_file(self, context):
    yield 'test1.csv'
    yield 'test2.csv'
    yield 'test3.csv'

@use_context_processor(input_file)
def extract(f):
    return bonobo.CsvReader(path=f,delimiter='|')

def load(*args):
    print(*args)

def get_graph(**options):
    graph = bonobo.Graph()
    graph.add_chain(extract,load)
    return graph
```

When I run the job I get something like `<bonobo.nodes.io.csv.CsvReader object at 0x7f849678dc88>` rather than the lines of the CSV.

If I hardcode the reader like `graph.add_chain(bonobo.CsvReader(path='test1.csv',delimiter='|'),load)`, it works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As bonobo.CsvReader does not support (yet) to read file names from the input stream, you need use a custom reader for that.

Here is a solution that works for me on a set of csvs I have:

```
import bonobo
import bonobo.config
import bonobo.util
import glob
import csv

@bonobo.config.use_context
def read_multi_csv(context, name):
    with open(name) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        headers = next(reader)
        if not context.output_type:
            context.set_output_fields(headers)
        for row in reader:
            yield tuple(row)

def get_graph(**options):
    graph = bonobo.Graph()

    graph.add_chain(
      glob.glob('prenoms_*.csv'),
      read_multi_csv,
      bonobo.PrettyPrinter(),
    )

    return graph


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with bonobo.parse_args() as options:
        bonobo.run(get_graph(**options))
```

Few comments on this snippet, in reading order:

- `use_context` decorator will inject the node execution context to the transformation call, allowing to use `.set_output_fields(...)` using the first csv headers.
- Other csv headers are ignored, in my case they're all the same. You may need a slightly more complex logic for your own case.
- Then, we just generate the filenames in a `bonobo.Graph` instance using `glob.glob` (in my case, the stream will contain: prenoms_2004.csv prenoms_2005.csv ... prenoms_2011.csv prenoms_2012.csv) and pass it to our custom reader, which will be called once for each file, open it, and yield its lines.

Hope that helps!